# Is there a sequence whose set of subsequence limits is $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> 1)Is there a sequence whose set of subsequence limits is  $(0,1)$?
>
> 2)Is there a sequence whose set of subsequence limits is  $\mathbb{Q}$?

for the first one my guess is yes , $\{a_n\}^\infty_1$ | $a_n=\frac{n}{2^n}$ is this correct and whats the answer for the second ?

Comment: For $\frac{n}{2^n}$, every subsequence converges to $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set of subsequence limits is always a closed subset of $\Bbb R$. So neither $(0,1)$ nor $\Bbb Q$ qualify.

Comment: so that's mean that i need to prove that the set of subsequence limits is always a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @E.Roi: you can find the proof in Rudin's Mathematical Analysis (Baby Rudin) and also, Charles Pugh's book on mathematical analysis that I'm not sure about its name.

Comment: okey , thanks alot

Comment: I mean, if $x$ is a limit point of the set of limit points of $(a_n)$, then it's a limit point of $(a_n)$, right?

Answer (score 0):

The set of limits is always a closed set.

> Then For the  first question it is well known that $u_n=\sin(n)$ is dense in [0,1]